# How do I handle keyboard events in GTK+3?

Tags: c, gtk3, keyboard-events

What signals/functions should I use to get keyboard input in GTK+3?

I have looked around and the only tutorials I know of that cover GTK+3 ([zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/) and [gnome developer](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html)) don't seem to cover that.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks very much - I will give it a go!

Comment: @xing You might want to put that into an answer

Comment: @PintoDoido If you are still interested in `GTK3` than [Take a look here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeZXCNsTodx0EPcAfc6s0Ew/playlists).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will summarize here how to handle keyboard events in GTK3, which I hope will be useful since I cannot find it put together anywhere else.

Imagine you are using GTK+3 and you want your application to do something when you press the space key. This is how you do it:

- First enable the ***#GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK*** mask for your ***Gdk.Window***:

  ```
  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK);
  ```
- Then you connect the window with the ***keyboard_press()*** function:

  ```
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "key_press_event",
          G_CALLBACK (my_keypress_function), NULL);
  ```
- Define your ***keyboard_press()*** to something once the **space key** has been pressed:

  ```
  gboolean my_keypress_function (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data) {
      if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_space){
          printf("SPACE KEY PRESSED!");
          return TRUE;
      }
      return FALSE;
  }
  ```

Comment: Didn't work for me with "keyboard_press", had to use "key_press_event" instead.

Comment: Call me a nitpicker, but should add a semicolon to terminate the prinf()

Comment: More fundamentally, it won't compile for me: gcc complains about on_key_press not having been declared.

Comment: don't forget to add '\n' at the end of the printf message, or it will print it's output after the program exits

Comment: In case you need the constant for left `Ctrl` it's `Gdk.KEY_Control_L`. For left `Shift` it's `Gdk.KEY_Shift_L`

Answer (score 3):

it's 
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (on_key_press), NULL);

Comment: I would suggest adding a link to any source of documentation of this function, along with a little summary

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.