# gtk-rs: how to listen for keyboard events

Tags: rust, gtk3, gtk-rs

I am using `gtk-rs` and want to be able to detect when any key is pressed.

From some searching online, it seems like the way to do that in C is with `gtk_widget_add_events` and then `g_signal_connect`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100029/1115876) has a good explanation.

In Rust, I can call [`Widget::add_events`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/prelude/trait.WidgetExtManual.html#tymethod.add_events). I also found several definitions for [`g_signal_connect_*`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gobject_sys/fn.g_signal_connect_closure.html). But, these functions are `unsafe`, undocumented, and seem to take C types as arguments.

My question is:

1. In order to use [`gobject_sys::g_signal_connect_closure`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gobject_sys/fn.g_signal_connect_closure.html), how do I create a `GObject` and `GClosure`. In Rust? Can rust structs and closures be converted to that?
2. Is there a better and more idiomatic way to listen for key events? I have trouble believing that doing such a basic thing would require such an esoteric interface. I have seen some support for specific keyboard shortcuts or keyboard acceleration groups but I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples for just listening for key press events.

Comment: Use [`Widget::connect`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.Widget.html#method.connect)

Comment: **But, these functions are unsafe** I would like to know, what meas `ùnsafe` to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Thansk @Jmb, [`Widget::connect`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.Widget.html#method.connect) was the right way to go. But, that function is undocumented and has some very weird types. Here's how I figured out how to use it:

```rs
window
    .connect("key_press_event", false, |values| {
        // "values" is a 2-long slice of glib::value::Value, which wrap G-types
        // You can unwrap them if you know what type they are going to be ahead of time
        // values[0] is the window and values[1] is the event
        let raw_event = &values[1].get::<gdk::Event>().unwrap().unwrap();
        // You have to cast to the correct event type to access some of the fields
        match raw_event.downcast_ref::<gdk::EventKey>() {
            Some(event) => {
                println!("key value: {:?}", std::char::from_u32(event.get_keyval()));
                println!("modifiers: {:?}", event.get_state());
            },
            None => {},
        }

        // You need to return Some() of a glib Value wrapping a bool
        let result = glib::value::Value::from_type(glib::types::Type::Bool);
        // I can't figure out how to actually set the value of result
        // Luckally returning false is good enough for now.
        Some(result)
    })
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: Two notes: in the newer `gtk-rs` bindings, getters don't have `get_` in front of them anymore. So you'd use `keyval()` instead of `get_keyval()`, etc. Also, to construct a glib Value from something, just do `.to_value()` on that thing. So to return true, you'd do `(true).to_value()`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while looking for a solution to the same problem and couldn't get it to work like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553051/9346402).

Then I found an other way of achieving a key event handler:

There is the [`EventControllerKey`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/git/docs/gtk4/struct.EventControllerKey.html), on which you can connect to the `key-pressed`, `key-released` and `modifiers` signals. Then you just have to register the EventControllerKey on a window.

Minimal example:

```rust
// ... Application setup

let window = gtk::ApplicationWindow::builder()
    .application(app)
    .build();

let event_controller = gtk::EventControllerKey::new();

event_controller.connect_key_pressed(|_, key, _, _| {
    match key {
        gdk::Key::Escape => {
            std::process::exit(0);
        }
        _ => (),
    }
    glib::Propagation::Proceed
});

window.add_controller(event_controller);
window.present();
```

I'm using this with `gtk4`.
Hope someone finds this useful.